# Determining elevation of a point from a DEM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, dem, coordinates, elevation

I have created a series of DEMs that layercake on top of each other.

I would like to be able to lookup a coordinate and get the elevation that has already been interpolated.  The goal is to introduce a new data point (coordinate and elevation) and determine which layer of the cake the new point is closest to.

I am using QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Point Sampling Plugin.  This can handle multiple points in the input file.  In the output you will have a series of fields named after your raster layers (the names may be truncated).  You can then compare your point elevation to the values in the fields and perhaps create a new field populated via a conditional expression that finds the nearest match and gives a value to each point that identifies the relevant DEM layer.